# How to store data from iOS app in a remote database safely and Apple friendly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database

How would one go about incorporating, for example a 'mailing list' where user could fill in a text field for 'name' and 'email address' and click a submit button that would add the data to a database on a remote server.
Property lists would be the most convenient but the whole plist would need to be downloaded to the users device, modified and reuploaded (which looks involved and easily corrupted). SQLite is likewise built for a local database. Is there a simple way to do this or is server side php scripting the only real answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear the most practical method at this time is a remote MySQL (or similar) database queried from php scripts that are called from the app via NSURLRequests (. Information about the query can be sent using the _POST variable.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of replies about this question that specify a specific database type and programming solution. The real solution is a web service, of any kind, and a data store, of any kind.

This could be SQL Server with a web service written in ASP.NET. It could also just as easily be a MySQL database with an interface written in PHP. But for the love all things secure don't try to attach to a database directly.